# Convert from .gql to json or csv

Tags: vaticle-typedb, vaticle-typeql

How to convert gql file (grakn) to json or csv?
I read the documentation provided by grakn.ai and there are only detailed explanation of how to convert different file formats to gql provided.

Here: https://grakn.ai/pages/documentation/migration/migration-overview.html

is explained how to do it:

Exporting Data from Grakn
It is also possible to export data from Grakn using the migration shell script. Usage is as follows:

```
    usage: graql migrate export -data -schema [-help] [-no] [-batch <arg>] [-uri <arg>] [-keyspace <arg>]
     -data                 export data
     -schema               export schema
     -h,--help             print usage message
     -k,--keyspace <arg>   keyspace to use
     -n,--no               dry run- write to standard out
     -u,--uri <arg>        uri to engine endpoint
     -r, --retry           Number of times to retry sending tasks if engine is not available
     -d,--debug            Migration immediatly stops if any transaction fails
```

Exporting data or the schema from Grakn, into Graql, will always redirect to standard out.

But I'm afraid, I don't understand how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid you can't export from Grakn into other data formats. The export function is exclusively designed to export your data and schema into a graql file so you can more easily transfer it to **another** running instance of Grakn.

Something similar to getting a SQL dump from a SQL database.

You can export your schema with the following command:

```
graql migrate export -schema -keyspace mykeyspace
```

and your data with this

```
graql migrate export -data -keyspace mykeyspace
```

where `mykeyspace` is the name of your keyspace

Answer (score 1):

You can try this graphql to json converter: https://github.com/jarnojellesma/graphql-json-converter

### How to use

- Open the graphql file
- Convert it
- Write it to a json file

**Example**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const schema = fs.readFileSync('./example/schema.gql', "utf8");
const convert = require('./gql-json-converter');

const jsonSchema = convert(schema);

fs.writeFile('./example/generated-schema.json', 
    JSON.stringify(jsonSchema, null, 2) + '\n', 
    'utf8', 
    function (err) {
      if (err) console.log(err);
});
```

### Output

```
{
  "type": {
    "User": {
      "id": {
        "type": "Int",
        "array": false,
        "required": true
      },
      "name": {
        "type": "String",
        "array": false,
        "required": true
      },
      "avatar": {
        "type": "Photo",
        "array": false,
        "required": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The question is asking about Grakn's Graql language files. Which are also appended with `.gql`. It's not asking about GraphQL. I am guessing that's why you were downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

The current version of graql now supports exporting to json as desired.

To convert graql queries/schema output use the `--output` option.

```
graql console -o json --keyspace YOUR_EPIC_GRAPH --file INSIGHTFUL_QUERY.gql
```

See current options with `graql console --help`. 
Supported formats are not listed, however.

```
usage: graql console
...
-o,--output <arg>     output format for results
...
```

Comment: This feature has been removed as of Grakn versoin 1.5.8.